# Getting error when assigning a SOQL query to list variable

Tags: trigger

I am getting this error "unexpected token: 'name'" from this piece in my trigger. Why?

```
trigger trgr_Related_Staff_Position on Related_Staff_Positions__c (after insert,after update,after delete) 
{


    List<ConRelated_Staff_Positions__ctact> rsp_List = new List<Related_Staff_Positions__c>();
    rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , first name, last name from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Contact__c IN: Trigger.New];
```

Comment: `First name` and `last name` are custom fields isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I forgot the proper syntax. Please me this an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having spaces between words. Try using below

```
rsp_LIst = [Select Contact__c , firstname__c, lastname__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Contact__c IN: Trigger.New];
```

Still this depends on your correct API name of the field. It may be `first_name__c` and `last_name__c`. Check the field API name from the object view if it's not sure.